# DDD - Using a Process Manager or a Domain Service

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am new with DDD and I am implementing it on a part of my application because some of the requirements of the application lead me to CQRS with Event Sourcing (need of historic of events that occured in the system plus need to be able to view the state of the system in the past).
One question I have after reading Vaughn Vernon book and its Effective Aggregate Design series is what is the difference between Process Manager (Long Running Porcess) and Domain Service. Especially when you have navigation properties towards an Aggregate into another Aggregate

I'll explain what I have understood :
- Domain services are made to hold logic that does not belong into any Aggregate. According to Vaughn it can be used as well to pass entities reference to the aggregate that contains it. It maybe used also to manage transactions as they cannot be handle into a Domain Object 
- Process manager are made to orchestrate modifications that are made on a system and spans on different aggregates. Some people are saying that a good Process Manager is actually an Aggregate Root. From my understanding it does not manage transactions as events are launched after changes are committed. It uses the approach of eventual consistency. Eventually all the changes will have occured

Now, to put everything in context. The core of the application I am building is to handle a tree of Nodes that contains their own logic. We need to be able to add Nodes to the Tree and of course to create those Nodes. 
We need to be able to know what happened to those Node. ie we need to be able to retrieve the event linked to a node 
Also a modification that is done to one of the leaves (depending of the kind of modification) will have to be replicated to the other Nodes that are a parent of this node.

What are my aggregates :
-  Nodes, it is what my tree contains. In my opinion this is an aggregate for several reasons. It is not an invariant, therefore not a value object. They have their own domain logic that allows them to assign it's properties it's value objects and we need to be able to access them using Ids 
- A representation of a non binary Tree made of Nodes. Right now, I actually designed this as my aggregate Root and it is actually a Process Manager. The tree contains a logic representation of this tree. It contains the root of the tree. This root is actually an Object (I am not sure it can be named a Value Object because it contains reference towards other aggregates, Child Nodes, but it certainly sounds like it is). The Node Object in the Tree contains basic information like the Node Name, and the reference towards the actual Aggregate (this almost sounds like two bounded context ?)

Using that approach this is what is happening :
- After executing the command to create a Node, a Node is created and committed. The NodeCreated Event is launched, caught by the correct Handler that retrieves the Tree (process manager) associated to this node and add the node at the correct place (using the parent id property of the Node)
- After executing the command to modify a Node, the node is modified and committed. The NodeModified Event is launched, caught by the handler. The Handler then retrieves the Tree (my process manager) and find all the Parent Node of the modified Node and ask for those Node to modify their own properties based on what was modified on the Child Node. This all makes perfect sense, and looks almost beautiful to me, showing the power of events and the seperation of domain logic

But, My principal issue here is with the transaction. What happens if an error happens while updating the Tree and the node that has to be modified  or added? The event for the Node is already saved in the Event Store, because it was committed. So i would have to create a new Event to revert the modifications ? I know that commands have to be valid when entering the system so it would not be a validation issue, and chances that something happening are like 1 in a million. Does that mean we should not take that possibility in account ?

The transaction issue is why I feel like I should use a Service. Either a Application Service (here a command handler) or a domain Service to orchestrate the mofications and do them in a Single Transaction. If something fails during this transaction, nothing is created/modified but that breaks the rule of DDD saying that I should not modify several Aggregates in the same Transaction. This somehow looks a less elegant solution

I really feel like I am missing something here but I am not quite sure what it is.

Answer (score 1):

> Some people are saying that a good Process Manager is actually an Aggregate Root

From my point of view this is not correct. A Process manager or a Saga coordinates a long running Business process that spans multiple Aggregate instances. It brings the system eventually in a valid final state. It does not emit events but respond to events and creates Commands that arrive to the Aggregates (possibly through a Command handler, depending on your exact architecture). Those architects that say that have failed to correctly identify they Aggregate boundaries.

A Process manager/Saga could be stateful - but just to *remember* the progress that it has made; it can have a Process ID; it can even be Event-sourced.

> Process manager are made to orchestrate modifications that are made on a system and spans on different aggregates.

Yes, this is correct.

> After executing the command to modify a Node, the node is modified and committed.

When you design your Aggregates you must take into consideration only the protection of invariants, of the business rules that exists on the write/command side of the architecture; this is the side that produce the state transition, the emitting of the events in case of Event-driven architectures.

The single business rule, if any, that I have identified on your specific case is that when a node is *created* (seems like a CRUD operation!) the `NodeCreated` Event is emitted; similar to `NodeModified`. So, these operations exist on the write/command side.

> The NodeModified Event is launched, caught by the handler. The Handler then retrieves the Tree (my process manager) and find all the Parent Node of the modified Node and ask for those Node to modify their own properties based on what was modified on the Child Node

Are there any business rules for the write side regarding the updating of the Parents nodes? I don't see any. Of course, something is updated after a Node is created but it is not an Aggregate but a Read model. Your Handler that is called is in fact a Read model. It projects the NodeXXX events on a Tree of Nodes.

Comment: When you ask if there are some business rules regarding the update of the Parent Nodes, the only one I have now it that it has to take in accounts it's own state. Meaning depending of the value that was updated the value is changed accordingly and so on. The parent node of the parent node will be updated using the value of its own child. But I fail to understand if I don't record thoses event, how can I rebuild the state of my tree and it's nodes in the past if I only save the modification in a read state ?

Comment: @Guigui yes, but are these new values (that are stored on the parent node) used by the parent node when it process a future command? Or are they just used to be displayed to the user?

Comment: Sorry misunderstood the question. Yes they will have to be used to run some logic afterward. For example to return a sub-tree with nodes that only contains a given value

Comment: @Guigui but this is query/read type of logic, not write/command type of logic used by an Aggregate.

Comment: @Guigui let me ask you other way: is this information used by an Aggregate (i.e. the Node) to reject or accept a command?

Comment: No, this is not going to accept or reject any commands. But there will be some logic associated to it later on. Basically, everything is possible in the tree. We can add, remove nodes and edit them as we like but later on we will have to go navigate through it and check its properties to see if it is correct. To me this sounds like domain logic even if it is a query

Comment: @Guigui yes, indeed, Domain logic but query side. This means no-Saga, only a Read model. Read models differ to Sagas. Read models can be re-created at any time, Sagas can't. Sagas send commands, Read models don't and so on. It is very important to correctly identify the type of the component.

Comment: It sounds like it was the part I was missing. In my mind, a Read Model did not have any logic. But what you are saying makes sense. Let me read more about that.

Comment: @Guigui glad to help. Read models are very important, and it is also the side that the users see. 10 big books could be written only about Read models.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167583/discussion-between-guigui-and-constantin-galbenu).

Answer (score 0):

> I really feel like I am missing something here but I am not quite sure what it is.

You may have over complicated your domain model.

Domain Services are typically *service providers* that give the domain model access to (cached) state or capabilities it wouldn't normally have.  For instance, we might use a domain service to give the model access to a cached tax table, so that it can compute the tax on an order; or we might use a domain service to give the model access to a notifyCustomer capability that is delegated to the email infrastructure.

Process Managers are usually used for orchestration - they are basically state machines that look at what has happened (events) and suggest additional commands to run.  See [Rinat Abdullin's description](https://abdullin.com/post/ddd-evolving-business-processes-a-la-lokad/).

> What happens if an error happens while updating the Tree and the node that has to be modified or added? The event for the Node is already saved in the Event Store, because it was committed. So i would have to create a new Event to revert the modifications ?

Maybe - compensating events are a common pattern.

The main point is this: there is no magic in orchestrating a change across multiple transactions.  Think about how you would arrange a UI that displays to a human operator what's going on, what should happen next, and what the failure modes would be.

> chances that something happening are like 1 in a million. Does that mean we should not take that possibility in account ?

Depends on the risk to the business.  But as Greg Young points out in his talk [Stop Over Engineering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GRr4xeMn1uU), if you can just escalate that 1 in a million problem to the human beings to sort out, you may have done enough.